# Do you know a WPF MonthPicker control?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm looking for a MonthPicker control, a control just like a DatePicker but that you can only select the month and the year.

Before start writing one from scrath I would like to know if something like this exists.

Comment: Aren't two simple drop-down lists or textboxes enough?

Comment: Yes, maybe, I was thinking about making something a little more advanced with a drop-down with month and years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used **System.Windows.Controls.Calendar** in this way:

[image: Calendaer used as MonthPicker]

(that's in Hebrew, but I'd guess you got the Idea...)

XAML:

```
<Calendar Name="dteSelectedMonth" DisplayMode="Year" SelectionMode="None" 
          DisplayModeChanged="dteSelectedMonth_DisplayModeChanged" />
```

Code behind to keep calendar on Year mode:

```
    private void dteSelectedMonth_DisplayModeChanged(object sender, CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        dteSelectedMonth.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
    }
```

And I've used **dteSelectedMonth.DisplayDate** value to get the selected month.

You might want to insert that **Calendar** into an **Expander** or a ComboBox with binding to SelectedMonth

Comment: This will only work if you have enough space available to always keep the calendar "open". It does not have the ability to drop down like combo boxes.

Comment: I combined this with `OnDisplayModeChanged(..) { if (e.NewMode == CalendarMode.Month) { calendarControl.DisplayMode = DisplayMode.Year; CloseCalendar(); }`

Answer (score 1):

Finally made my own. It needs some polish, but works:

[image]

Usercontrol VB code at https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/16351501/MonthPicker.zip

Comment: @Marshal: I'll send you the code by email (it you provide one). Beware it's VB code and that I'm not longer developing in WPF, so it's dead code.

Comment: @EduardoMolteni OK - it was great talking to you.I'll delete my comments now.

Answer (score 0):

The WPF Toolkit DatePicker can have its Calendar re-styled.

You could also override the string format on the textbox in the DatePicker to only display the Month and Year.

You can see some examples and discussion [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882520.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but has been there. Was looking for something already made.